# Where is my POST() data going

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

I'm developing a regular form in html using Jquery Ajax and PHP.

When i send the email via php function mail, i'm receiving the next email with the empty fields and I don't know why:

```
From: 
E-Mail: 
Message:
```

The code I'm using:

-PHP (sendMail.php):

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $name    = $_POST['form_name'];
    $email   = $_POST['form_email'];
    $content = $_POST['form_content'];
    $from    = 'Koke Contact Form';
    $to      = 'wheretosendit@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Someone is contacting';
    $body    = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $content";

    //send email

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
                $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

-HTML

```
<form method = "post" id = "message" action = "sendMail.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "yourinfo col-md-6">
            <div class = "form-group" id = "nombre">
                <label for = "input-name"> Tu nombre: </label>
                <input id= "form-name" type= "text" class= "form-control gborder" name = "form-name">
            </div>          
            <div class = "form-group " id = "email">
                <label for = "input-email"> Tu email: </label>
                <input id = "form-email" type= "email" class= "form-control gborder" name = "form-email">
            </div>
        </div>                          
        <div class = "form-group col-md-6" id = "comment">
            <label for = "input-content"> Mensaje: </label>
            <textarea id = "form-content" class="form-control gborder" rows = "5" name = "form-content"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class = "text-center">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

-JQUERY

```
$('#message').submit(function() {
    if($('#form-name').val() !== "" && $('#form-email').val() !== "" && $('#form-content').val() !== "") {
        var data = {
            name: $('#form-name').val(),
            email: $('#form-email').val(),
            content: $('#form-content').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'sendMail.php',
            data: data,
            success: function () {              
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                $('#form-content').val("");
                $('#form-name').val("");
                $('#form-email').val("");
            }
        });
    } return false;
});
```

As I said, I'm receiving the email but the From, E-mail and Message fields are empty. I've been fighting with this since 2 days ago.. I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You send from js array

```
var data = {
    name: $('#form-name').val(),
    email: $('#form-email').val(),
    content: $('#form-content').val()
};
```

But in php you try to access to other fields

```
$name    = $_POST['form_name'];
$email   = $_POST['form_email'];
$content = $_POST['form_content'];
```

Ajax `name` and in php `form_name`, but must be `name` too.

Comment: than you!! that was it